# storing image into SQLite in android

Tags: android, sqlite

hai all i want to store an image in SQLite database.that was selected from SD card.

After searching in the google i found that BLOB is the way to store image in database.

this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028751/how-to-display-image-from-blob-data-in-android-sqlite) followed to insert but it does not work for me, 
how to convert a image into blob?

how can i store image in the database in blob format?

can anyone give me the sample to store the image in database?

Please help me....

Comment: What bit of that "doesn't work for you"?

Comment: thank you reply.what about database code?i didnt get the database side code in that link

Comment: At least paste a code example of what you've got so far. That's more likely to get people to help you

Comment: sorry, i used same code convert image into byte array, but my question is how to insert image(converted byte array) into database?

Comment: it is very easy to deal with image as BLOB just refer this link you wil get to know for sure
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6815355/how-to-store-image-retreived-from-url-in-a-sqlite-database/6815819#6815819

Answer (score 4):

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.thumbnail);

ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);

ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

cv.put(KEY_IMAGE, out.toByteArray());

db.insert(DB_TABLE, null, cv);
```

A full example http://www.anddev.org/png_image_--und-gt_sqlite_db_--und-gt_imageview-t7188.html