# Which storage mechanism will suit for Android and IOS in my scenario?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Let me describe my scenario first.

1. I want to build an PhongeGap app for Android[4+] and IOS[5,6,7].
2. In which I want to store data around 3 to 4MB at max.
3. A user can use the app upto 2yrs of duration.

I read the [PhoneGap Documentation on storage](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage). According to the document WebSQL would be the sufficient implementation.

The followings are the factor why I am rethinking about WebSQL.

1. Will there be any support issue or compatibility issue in IOS,
2. Long term usage of the app so we should not compromise the data [WebSQL is Webstorage] &
3. Clearing the cache, Install/Uninstall of browser, clearing temp shouldn't cause the loss of data.

Suggest a Storage mechanism in my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `html5 localstorage` for your storage because it support until 5mb.

Comment: Fine. What would be the suggest way if I want to include images as a part of storage?

Comment: as long not more than 5mb if you want to use localstorage. if image I suggest you use sqlite.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908480/storing-image-into-sqlite-in-android

Comment: Its really a good article. But the article explains about android what about IOS?

Comment: same. no need to worry about :)

Comment: Storing image in sqlite is proper way or any other is recommended to achieve in android and ios.