# How to insert the image in SQLite database from gallery in android with person data

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to create a form where the person can save his data with upload image option. And save all data in SQLiteDatabase.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer [storing image into SQLite in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6908480/storing-image-into-sqlite-in-android)
but actually storing images in database not a good practice. 
Better save image on SD Card and insert into DB only path to this image.

Official tutorial how to save data in SQLite http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: When I saved the image using uri path its show me this error after click on uri path:

Comment: 01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at android.content.ContentResolver.openInputStream(ContentResolver.java:436)
01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at com.example.uripath.MainActivity$4.onClick(MainActivity.java:98)
01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4452)

Comment: 01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18428)
01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5365)

Comment: @user3881947 , post please your code as edit to your main question

Comment: 01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)

Comment: 01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)

Comment: 01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
01-17 10:23:36.312: E/AndroidRuntime(22875):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: @user3881947, I'm sorry, how do you want me to read it? Edit your question and post everything there. All these comments remove please, nobody does like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert image in byte array format in sqlite.
To store byte array you need to define a column with blob type format.

and then you can simply do like that :-

```
public void storeImage(Bitmap img){
    byte[] data = getBitmapAsByteArray(img);     

     SQLiteDatabase db=database.getWritableDatabase();
     db.execSQL("INSERT INTO IMAGETABLE VALUES(data);");
}

public static byte[] getBitmapAsByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, outputStream);       
    return outputStream.toByteArray();
}
```